# Blazor route with encrypted parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

How can I make my Blazor application to receive the encrypted parameters that contain the encoded special characters such as `"/"` and `"+"`.

My screenshot can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JRml.png)

How should I configure the Blazor parameters, so that they are split and translated correctly?

Comment: Why dont you just escape those characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make my Blazor application to receive

First, the sending application has to format it properly for URL use. And you have to know that formatting.

In .NET you can use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` and then `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` in the Blazor page.

Answer (score -1):

You may try `Base64UrlEncoder` from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`